# Setting up the preact testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, preact

I have a question related with preact-testing-library. I faced with a strange problem: when I try to render something (using `render` function from `@testing-library/preact`), it returns undefined. 
 Assume I have a simple component:

```
import { h } from 'preact';
import { useState } from 'preact/hooks';

export function Counter({ initialCount }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  const increment = () => setCount(count + 1);

  return (
    <div>
      Current value: {count}
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And I want to test it. My test file looks like:

```
import { expect } from 'expect';
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from '@testing-library/preact';
import { h } from 'preact';
import Counter from './Dummy.jsx';

describe('Counter', () => {
  test('should display initial count', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Counter initialCount={5}/>);
    console.log('container', container.innerHTML)
    expect(container.textContent).toMatch('Current value: 5');
  });
});
```

The test fails, and in the terminal I have message: `container <undefined initialcount="5"></undefined>` from my  `console.log`. Seems that it just replaces the JSX to undefined.

Here is a fragment from my `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    testMatch: [
      //some pathes to my test files
    ],
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(preact|@testing-library)/)'],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
      '<rootDir>/node_modules/'
    ],
    moduleFileExtensions: [
      'js',
      'jsx'
    ],
    moduleDirectories: [
      'node_modules'
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
      '^react$':     'preact/compat',
      '^react-dom$': 'preact/compat'
    },
    setupFiles: [
      '<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'
    ],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mjs)$": "babel-jest",
    },
};
```

And this is `babel.config.js` file:

```
const testingConfig = {

  plugins: [
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", { "pragma":"h" }],
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',

  ],
  presets: [
    '@babel/react',
    '@babel/preset-env'
  ],
};
```

Where is the problem? Why does the `render` skip the JSX (or replaces it to undefined)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a typo, you are using named exports to export the `Counter` component.

You should import it like this:

```
import { Counter } from './Dummy.jsx';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
testMatch: ['**/*.test.js'],
```

you should write type of your file in testMatch.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35339363)